# Display Large Image on mouse hover with auto position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem to Display Large Image on mouse hover with auto positioning.All images on mouse hover showing right side and on right side it out of boundary and also it take extra space bottom side.
here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#portfolio li').click(function() {
  // fetch the class of the clicked item
  var ourClass = $(this).attr('class');
  
  // reset the active class on all the buttons
  $('#filterOptions li').removeClass('active');
  // update the active state on our clicked button
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  
  if(ourClass == 'all') {
   // show all our items
   $('#portfolio').children('section.item').show(1000); 
  }
  else {
   // hide all elements that don't share ourClass
   $('#portfolio').children('section:not(.' + ourClass + ')').hide(1000);
   // show all elements that do share ourClass
   $('#portfolio').children('section.' + ourClass).show(1000);
  }
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
.Enlarge {
position:relative;
height:150px;
width:250px;
}    
.Enlarge span {
position:absolute;
left: -9999px;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
-ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
   
div.Enlarge:hover{
z-index: 999;
cursor:pointer;
}    
div.Enlarge:hover span{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
top: 50px;
left: 0px;
width:500px;
height:300px;
padding: 5px;
background:#9f499b;

}
```

```html
<section class="item brochure">
<div class="Enlarge">
    small image 1
    <span>large image 1</span>
</div>
</section>
<section class="item brochure">
<div class="Enlarge">
    smal image 2
    <span>large image 2</span>
</div>
</section>
<section class="item brochure">
<div class="Enlarge">
    small image 3
    <span>small image 3</span>
</div>
</section>
<section class="item brochure">
<div class="Enlarge">
    small image 4
    <span>large image 4</span>
</div>
</section>
```

[here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSMRl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/oqzekcv8/5/

The script will use javascript (and jquery) to show and hide the images, one thing worth noting is that the script will behave badly if the coordinates for the image you are showing are the same as your cursors, so i have offset them with 5 pixels down and to the left.

If for some reason fiddle is down here is the script itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Enlarge').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.expandedImage').show();
        var container = $(this);
        var containerOffset = container.offset();
        var largeImage = container.find('.expandedImage');
        $(container).on('mousemove.imageFollow', function(event){
            var left = event.pageX - containerOffset.left + 5;
            var top = event.pageY - containerOffset.top  + 5;
            if(event.clientX + largeImage.width() + 5 >= $(window).width())
                left = $(window).width() - largeImage.width() - containerOffset.left -2;
            if(event.clientY + largeImage.height() + 5 >= $(window).height())
                top = $(window).height() - largeImage.height() - containerOffset.top -2;
            largeImage.css('left', left).css('top', top);
        });
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).off('mousemove.imageFollow');
        $(this).closest('.Enlarge').find('.expandedImage').hide();
    });
});
```

and it will work on a structure like this:

```
<section class="item brochure">
    <div class="Enlarge">
        small image 1
        <div class="expandedImage">large image 1</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

the css for this is:

```
.Enlarge {
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:visible;
}
.Enlarge .expandedImage {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color:blue;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    z-index:10000;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

the white-space:nowrap is to prevent the browser from cutting your demo text into smaller pieces, it will work without that if you only display an image instead of text

Also note that it binds the mousemove event on mouseenter and unbinds it on mouseleave, i can't motivate that, i just happend to do that out of old habit, but now you know how to do that as well :)

**Also note: pointer-events:none; does not work in IE as far as i know, so the image will "keep it self open" if you get it to the lower right corner of the page as long as you keep your pointer over the expanded image (it is intended to make the element not receive mouse events)**

Comment: but i want that if i hover image the most right then it should show hover image to auto left side because of website boundary.

Comment: you can see image i give the link also so you will understand better .

Comment: I have updated the example, it still does not do what you want it to do, but do you think this is okay? (You can just check the link at the top first and see if it functions in an acceptable way before you look at the changes in the code). Either it was more complicated then i thought, or i am simply getting to tired in my head :P Is this okay, or do you really want it to jump to the right side of the cursor? (I can see scenarios where you actually do want it on the other side instead of just sticking to the border like it does now..) (You can resize the preview box to see how it works)

Comment: Ya like, it works, or ya like you need it to swap sides? :) Also: you are welcome!